# PHP Append <span> after <input> on form submit

Tags: php, html

I have to build a calculator with php. When i press the submit buttom, if the value of x isn't a number i have to display a span error after the input label.

```
<form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return keepCombobox();">
        <h1>Multiplicador</h1>
        <!--Draws the box around the related elements-->
        <fieldset>
            <p id="x">
                <!--If the label is pressed, sends the focus to the input-->
                <label for="x">X: </label>

                <input type="text" id="x" name="x" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($x, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?>"/>
            </p>

            <p id="y">
                <!--If the label is pressed, sends the focus to the input-->
                <label for="y">Y: </label>
                <input type="text" id="y" name="y" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($y, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?>"/><br><!--span style="color: red">valor nao valido</span-->
            </p>

            <p>
                <select name="op" required>
                    <option value=""<?php if ($op == "") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>-- Operação --</option>
                    <option value="+"<?php if ($op == "+") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Soma</option>
                    <option value="-"<?php if ($op == "-") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Subtração</option>
                    <option value="*"<?php if ($op == "*") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Multiplicação</option>
                    <option value="/"<?php if ($op == "/") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Divisão</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <!--Button-->
                <input type="submit" value="Calcular"/>
            </p>

            <?php
                if ($_GET){
            ?>

            <p>
                <?php
                if (!is_numeric($x)){
                    echo "<br><span style=\"color: red\">valor nao valido</span>";
                } else if (!is_numeric($y)) {
                    echo "<br><span style=\"color: red\">valor nao valido</span>";
                } else {
                    switch($op){
                    case '+':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x + $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x - $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x * $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        if ($y == 0) {
                            echo "Não é possível dividir por zero";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "O resultado é  " . ($x / $y) ;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </p>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I want to know how i can append the

```
br><span style="color: red">valor nao valido</span>
```

after the input where i get the value

Comment: for that javaScript might come handy

Comment: you can use type="number" and replace type="text" to  type="number" .. <input type="number">

Comment: what issue you are currently facing is there any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple answer if someone have the same problem

```
<input type="text" id="y" name="y" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($y, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") ?>"/><?php if (array_key_exists("y", $_GET) && !is_numeric($y)) { ?><br><span style="color: red">valor nao valido</span><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like that :

```
<form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return keepCombobox();">
    <h1>Multiplicador</h1>
    <!--Draws the box around the related elements-->
    <fieldset>
        <p id="x">
            <!--If the label is pressed, sends the focus to the input-->
            <label for="x">X: </label>

            <input type="number" id="x" name="x" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($x, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?>"/>
            <?php 
            if (isset($x) && !is_numeric($x)) {
                ?><br><span style="color: red">valor nao valido</span><?php
            }
            ?>
        </p>

        <p id="y">
            <!--If the label is pressed, sends the focus to the input-->
            <label for="y">Y: </label>
            <input type="number" id="y" name="y" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($y, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?>"/>

            <?php 
            if (isset($y) && !is_numeric($y)) {
                ?><br><span style="color: red">valor nao valido</span><?php
            }
            ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <select name="op" required>
                <option value=""<?php if ($op == "") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>-- Operação --</option>
                <option value="+"<?php if ($op == "+") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Soma</option>
                <option value="-"<?php if ($op == "-") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Subtração</option>
                <option value="*"<?php if ($op == "*") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Multiplicação</option>
                <option value="/"<?php if ($op == "/") { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Divisão</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <!--Button-->
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular"/>
        </p>
        <?php if (isset($x) && isset($y) && is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y)): ?>
            <p><?php
                switch($op) {
                    case '+':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x + $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x - $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        echo "O resultado é  " . ($x * $y) ;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        if ($y == 0) {
                            echo "Não é possível dividir por zero";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "O resultado é  " . ($x / $y) ;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've moved the `is_numeric` tests below the input fields to display the span where you want to.

Then I've also updated the input type to use `number`. This custom type will tell the browser that the field must be a number so if supported it'll apply some validation before submitting form. If not supported, it'll be handled as a simple text input.

At the end of the script I've updated your test, you don't want to rely on $_GET because the only important thing here is to check if $x and $y are defined.

Pay attention to your code, it seems that you are using [register_globals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is not supported anymore in PHP since PHP 5.4.0.

Your code wont be able to execute on more recent PHP version.

You must define variable like that before using them :

```
<?php
    $x = isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:0;
    $y = isset($_GET['y'])?$_GET['y']:0;
    $op = isset($_GET['op'])?$_GET['op']:'';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your GET value in variable :

```
<?php
if ($_GET){
if(isset($_GET['x']) && $_GET['x'] != ''){$x = $_GET['x'];}else{$x = '';}
if(isset($_GET['y']) && $_GET['y'] != ''){$y = $_GET['y'];}else{$x = '';}
if(isset($_GET['op']) && $_GET['op'] != ''){$x = $_GET['op'];}else{$x = '';}
?>
```